# SQL XML Parser Error: illegal name character

Tags: sql, xml

I am trying to execute the following query:

```
SELECT CASE CAST(a.AnswerText as XML).value('(/AnswerData/Input[@Name = "AnswerData0"]/Value)[1]', 'varchar(100)')
WHEN 'Other' THEN 'Self'
WHEN 'man' THEN 'Manager'
WHEN 'sub' THEN 'Suborbinate'
WHEN 'Colleague' THEN 'Colleague'
ELSE (CAST(a.AnswerText as XML).value('(/AnswerData/Input[@Name = "AnswerData0"]/Value)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)'))
END as RelationShip, ta.TestAssignmentId
```

This is just a snippet of a much larger query, but this is where the error is being caused.
The error being outputted is:

```
XML parsing: line 1, character 67, illegal name character
```

I realised this was a problem with the XML, so I checked the XML and it seems ok to me:

```
<AnswerData><Input Name="AnswerData0" Correct="false"><Value>Other</Value></Input></AnswerData>
<AnswerData><Input Name="AnswerData0" Correct="true"><Value>sub</Value></Input></AnswerData>
<AnswerData><Input Name="AnswerData0" Correct="false"><Value>Colleague</Value></Input></AnswerData>
<AnswerData><Input Name="AnswerData0" Correct="true"><Value>sub</Value></Input></AnswerData>
<AnswerData><Input Name="AnswerData0" Correct="false"><Value>Colleague</Value></Input></AnswerData>
<AnswerData><Input Name="AnswerData0" Correct="false"><Value>man</Value></Input></AnswerData>
<AnswerData><Input Name="AnswerData0" Correct="false"><Value>Colleague</Value></Input></AnswerData>
```

Can anyone provide an insight or notice something in the XML which I have missed.

Comment: you xml is fine and query should work too (it's a bit wierd but I don't know what you want to get). Looks like you have some illegal char in another rows xml data. Why do you need to cast, is your xml stored as varchar column or do you create it on the fly?

Comment: Its stored as a varchar which is why it needs to be cast

Comment: have you tried to do plain `select cast(AnswerText as xml) from <your table>`? Just to see if there's problems in your xml data?

Comment: What is the encoding of the XML data? Have you tried different ones?

Comment: Are you writing **SQL** (structured query language) and really mean Microsoft **SQL Server** (the actual product) by this? If yes: please add `sql-server` tag to make this clear. If not: **what** database system is this for?
+

Comment: @marc_s for me it's 100% sql server because of value function, but there're might be some other RDBMS having exact same syntax :)

Comment: @RomanPekar: I agree with your **guess** - but it would be nice if the folks asking those questions would **tell us** instead of leaving us guessing ....

Comment: @marc_s 100% agreed. Actually the question looks like OP have some problem with xml, something like special character maybe, like & or <. It happens when one stores xml as nvarchar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turned out, the reason I was getting the error was due to the fact `a.AnswerTest` was in fact returning `NULL`, which meant it could not be cast as XML.

In order to ensure `a.AnswerText` did not return `NULL` I added an extra `WHERE` clause to eliminate this from happening.

Comment: Thanks for reporting your solution back to us.